# How to make a new line in error message in RegexpValidator in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Could someone write me how to make a new line in error message in RegexpValidator in Vaadin?

I have method:

```
public TextField addPhoneNumberField(String value, String location, boolean readOnly) {
    final String PATTERN = "^[0][0-9\\s]*$";
    final RegexpValidator validator = new RegexpValidator(PATTERN, 
    "Phone number is not valid. Only numbers are allowed. Phone number must begin with zero");
    etc
```

I need have each sentence in new line. I tried to put there \n, \r\n, `<br/>`, but nothing is working.

Is it 
possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way (without extending Vaadin's client component VErrorMessage) is to use preformated text and use CSS rule for it.

For new line in java use: `\n`

And add style rule in used style.css file (example for all tooltip error messages):

```
.v-tooltip .v-errormessage {
    white-space: pre;
}
```